# How to handle list picker in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a  list picker which is displayed in my phone application page.I have created list picker in starting of class,and i am adding the list picker in the phoneApplicationPage_loaded() method.When the page is launched the first time, ,the scenario works perfectly and its navigates further to second page.When i navigate back to previous page(containing list picker),it shows Invalid Operation Exception occured stating "Element is already the child of another element."

I want to know how to handle these scenarios?

Code is below

namespace My.Design
{
    public partial class myclass : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

```
    String[] values = null;
    ListPicker picker = new ListPicker();
    StackPanel sp;
    StackPanel mainFrame;
    String statementInfo = "";

    public myclass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Phone Application Page Loaded_>>>>>>");
        List<String> source = new List<String>(); 
        displayUI();                   

    }

    public void displayUI()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("About to display UI in miniStatement");
        Debug.WriteLine("<-------------Data--------->");
        Debug.WriteLine(statementInfo);
        Debug.WriteLine("<-------------Data--------->");
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i);
                string childTypeName = child.GetType().ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("Elements in this Child" + childTypeName);
            }
        }
        List<String> source = new List<String>();

        String[] allParams = ItemString.Split('@');
        source.Add("PleaseSelect");
        for (int i = 0; i < allParams.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("All Params Length" + allParams[i]);
            if (!(allParams[i].Equals("") && (!allParams[i].Equals(null))))
            {
                if (values != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Values length" + values.Length);
                    values[values.Length] = allParams[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Allparams Length" + allParams[i]);
                    source.Add(allParams[i]);
                }

            }

        }
        //picker = new ListPicker();
        this.picker.ItemsSource = source;

        mainFrame = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock box = new TextBlock();
        box.Text = "> DEmoClass";
        box.FontSize = 40;

        mainFrame.Children.Add(box);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock box1 = new TextBlock();
        box1.Text = "Number";
        box1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        box1.FontSize = 40;
        SolidColorBrush scb1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        box1.Foreground = scb1;
        sp.Children.Add(box1);
        picker.Width = 400;
        picker.Height = 150;
        sp.Children.Add(picker);
        Canvas.SetTop(sp, 150);
        canvas.Children.Add(sp);
        mainFrame.Children.Add(canvas);
        this.ContentPanel1.Children.Add(mainFrame);
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        Debug.WriteLine("OnNavigatingFrom>>>.>>MainPage");
        if (sp != null)
        {
            sp.Children.Remove(picker);
        }*/
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide some code please.

Comment: added code ,Can you check it and tell me

Answer (score 1):

If you are not intending to update the listpicker after navigating back from the second page add the following line in your Loaded event handler

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Loaded -= PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded;
    Debug.WriteLine("Phone Application Page Loaded_>>>>>>");
    List<String> source = new List<String>(); 
    displayUI();                   

}
```

Comment: Thanks nkChandra for your inputs,I cannot use this option you suggessted for me because,I cannot use this case when my app gets Tombstoned,Is there any way to differentiate the app is tombstoned or not.?I was able to fix this issue ,by create stackPanel in XAml,and by on page loading ,I am doing like "   if (comboHolder.Children.Contains(picker))
                comboHolder.Children.Remove(picker);"to remove and then finally add the picker,This way works,Is there any suggestion you can give for me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you can not use that case when app resume from tombstoned.

error happened because when you back to your page , loaded event runs again.

by the way,

Application_Activated 's argument can tell you app resumes from tombstoned or not--.

if (e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved)
   {

```
   IsTombstoning = false;
```

}
   else
   {

```
   IsTombstoning = true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you're creating it in code and not leaving it in XAML? Also the error is coming from the fact that you're attempting to add it twice into a location that can probably only have a single content element.  What's the higher level problem you're trying to solve?